# Prevent recyclerview from overlapping with toolbar in coordinator layout

Tags: android

Im using the following layout. I want the recyclerview to appear below toolbar.
and I have also included the floating action button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbarLayout"
        layout="@layout/fragment_folder_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/folder_play_all_fab"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white_48dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="9dp"
        app:rippleColor="#888888"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbarLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem is that the recycler view in include tag is overlapping with toolbar.

How can I be able to prevent this from overlapping?

Comment: in your `RecycleView` add this property `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`.

Comment: will adding Linearlayout as parent to include solve the prob?

Comment: no it is not working even after trying that out